# Recorrido InOrden en árbol N-ario

Tags: c#, estructuras-de-datos

No puedo recorrer de manera recursiva el subárbol izquierdo ni el derecho con el método `arbol.EntreOrden();` porque el código me genera el siguiente error.

**System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'El argumento especificado está fuera del intervalo de valores válidos.
Nombre del parámetro: index'**

Aquí envío el código en C# de la clase ArbolGeneral y de la clase Program.

```
public class ArbolGeneral<T>
{
    private T dato;
    private LinkedList<ArbolGeneral<T>> hijos;
   
    public ArbolGeneral(T pDato)
    {
        hijos = new LinkedList<ArbolGeneral<T>>();
        dato = pDato;
    }
    public T getDato()
    {
        return dato;   
    }
    public LinkedList<ArbolGeneral<T>> getHijos()
    {
       return hijos;
    }
    public void AgregarHijo(ArbolGeneral<T> hijo)
    {
        getHijos().AddLast(hijo);   
    }
    public void EntreOrden() //Método con problema
    {
        foreach (var hijo in getHijos().ElementAt(0).hijos)
            hijo.EntreOrden();

        Console.WriteLine(dato);

        foreach (var hijo in getHijos().ElementAt(1).hijos)
            hijo.EntreOrden();
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase Program donde creo el árbol.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Raiz
        ArbolGeneral<string> arbol = new ArbolGeneral<string>("D");

        //Primer nivel
        ArbolGeneral<string> hijo1 = new ArbolGeneral<string>("E");
        ArbolGeneral<string> hijo2 = new ArbolGeneral<string>("G");

        arbol.AgregarHijo(hijo1);
        arbol.AgregarHijo(hijo2);

        //Segundo nivel
        ArbolGeneral<string> hijo3 = new ArbolGeneral<string>("F");
        ArbolGeneral<string> hijo4 = new ArbolGeneral<string>("H");
        ArbolGeneral<string> hijo5 = new ArbolGeneral<string>("J");
        ArbolGeneral<string> hijo6 = new ArbolGeneral<string>("M");

        hijo1.AgregarHijo(hijo3);
        hijo2.AgregarHijo(hijo4);
        hijo2.AgregarHijo(hijo5);
        hijo2.AgregarHijo(hijo6);

        ArbolGeneral<string> hijo7 = new ArbolGeneral<string>("I");
        ArbolGeneral<string> hijo8 = new ArbolGeneral<string>("K");
        ArbolGeneral<string> hijo9 = new ArbolGeneral<string>("L"); 

        hijo4.AgregarHijo(hijo7);
        hijo5.AgregarHijo(hijo8);
        hijo5.AgregarHijo(hijo9);
                       
        arbol.EntreOrden();

     }
```

¿Cómo pudiera solucionarlo para que imprima la salida esperada?

Gracias por anticipado.

Este es la imagen del árbol con la que estoy trabajando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 2 Preguntas: 1) Que lenguaje es este? y 2) que debería imprimir (salida esperada) ?

Comment: @Yussef el lenguaje es C# y lo que quiero es que se imprima la salida. Gracias

Comment: Pero cual es la salida según los datos que tu ingresaste. DEGFH ese orden?

Comment: @Yussef la salida esperada sería la siguiente:  F, E, D, I, H, G, K, J, L, M

Comment: Pero tú no tienes seteado ese árbol en el código publicado solo tienes los nodos DEGFH

Comment: @Yussef edité la pregunta y ya puse todo el código con el árbol seteado completo.

Comment: @Me parece que hay un error, en la salida, no debería ser: FEIHKLJMGD? me confirmas

Comment: @Yussef esa es la salida del PostOrden: F E, I, H, K, L, J, M, G, D                            la salida del PreOrden: D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M                                                      y la del EntreOrden: F, E, D, I, H, G, K, J, L, M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ArbolGeneral<T>
{
    private T dato;
    private LinkedList<ArbolGeneral<T>> hijos;

    public ArbolGeneral(T pDato)
    {
        hijos = new LinkedList<ArbolGeneral<T>>();
        dato = pDato;
    }
    public T getDato()
    {
        return dato;
    }
    public LinkedList<ArbolGeneral<T>> getHijos()
    {
        return hijos;
    }
    public void AgregarHijo(ArbolGeneral<T> hijo)
    {
        getHijos().AddLast(hijo);
    }
    public void PreOrden() //Método con problema
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dato);
        foreach (var hijo in getHijos())
            hijo.PreOrden();
    }
    public void PostOrden() //Método con problema
    {
        foreach (var hijo in getHijos())
            hijo.PostOrden();

        Console.WriteLine(dato);

    }
    public void EntreOrden()
    {
           
        foreach (var hijo in leftChild())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(hijo.dato);
        }
        for(int i=1; i<getHijos().Count; i++)
        {
            getHijos().ElementAt(i).EntreOrden();
        }
    }
     
    public Stack<ArbolGeneral<T>> leftChild()
    {
        Stack<ArbolGeneral<T>> stack = new Stack<ArbolGeneral<T>>();
        stack.Push(this);
        Stack<ArbolGeneral<T>> visitados = new Stack<ArbolGeneral<T>>();
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var n = stack.Pop();
            visitados.Push(n);

            if(n.getHijos().Count > 0)
            {
                stack.Push(n.getHijos().First());   
            }

        }
        return visitados;
    }

}
```

Explicación

1. Teniendo un Nodo se debe buscar los de la izquieda
2. Para esto está la función leftChild que busca en profundidad (en la primera iteración sería F E D). Por eso ocupamos una Pila, para que los valores vayan invertidos
3. Luego una función recursiva para el RESTO de los hijos, donde G pasa a ser el nodo padre y volveríamos al punto (1) buscaría en profundidad por la izquierda y retornaría I H G y así sucesivamente

Comment: que esté en orden ("In-order traversal") habria que examinar todos los hijos y visitar los que son menores que el nodo padre primero, luego el nodo padre, y luego los que son mayores al nodo padre.

Sino, no esta "en-orden". O sea, si tienes la raiz de tu arbol con un 3, y a la izquierda tienes 1,2 y a la derecha 4,5,6,7, entonces el recorrido "en orden" debe ser 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

Si recorridos en-orden son importantes, recomendaria usar tres punteros. Uno a los hijos menores, otro a los hijos mayores, un tercer puntero al nodo hermano. Asi es n-ario y mantiene orden.